# Query field disabled in edit data mode in pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I want to make a SELECT statement in the "View/Edit Data" mode in pgAdmin 4 but the query field is disabled. How can I enable it? (I have all privileges for all, the database, schema and table and I am the owner of all as well)

[image]

Comment: If you want to do a query you need to select the database, then under tools -> Query tools and typ in your query. The queries from View/edit data are uneditable. You can only edit the data itself

Comment: besides your question does not seem to have a spatial component and therefore is offtopic here. Rather try and ask it at [Database SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 12):

This happens when you view a specific number of records from your table by right clicking on it and pgAdmin4 allows you to only view the records and does not allow you to edit the query. The Query that you are viewing is simply the number selected that you specify.

If you want to edit the query, simply click you the table and then from Tools in the menu bar click on the Query Tool that will allow you to make edition to the query.

I hope it helps you to understand why, it can't be edited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was aware of that Query tool. I just would like to edit the data directly in the table in a subselection and not going through the whole table. And I thought this would be possible in the Edit Data view.

Comment: Yeah, it's very strange that it doesn't just let you edit the query.

Comment: It can also happen if you don't have a primary key on the table you wish to edit.

Comment: It's almost like it's deliberately blocked.  It's the same window - why not allow to edit??  You've got something on the clipboard to use.... Oh damn now I have to lose that and copy this boilerplate SELECT.   Maybe a "clone" button to just copy as editable? For those irritated like me on Windows look into WINKEY + V for all your clipboard needs.